# Proxy nginx to another nginx and then to application

Tags: nginx, proxy, keycloak

i have following setup.

**Network A** Nginx / SSL

**Network B** App1/preprod (keycloak preprod, wildfly preprod, database preprod)

**Network C** Nginx /SSL

**Network D** App1/test (keycloak test, wildflys test, database test)

Communication:

```
A <-> B
A <-> C
C <-> D
```

I am trying to:

```
NGINX A -> APP 1 preprod --- that is ok
NGINX A -> NGINX C -> APP 1 test --- that's what i am tryng to figure out.
```

Problem is that keycloak which is on APP1 test need to get request from NGINX A URL and not from NGINX C.

I appriciate your help,

Alan

Answer (score 1):

It's little bit difficult to understand actual problem here.

I assume you should dig into http headers while passing through nginx. You could pass same Host header even hostname does not resolve to Nginx C. Just use upstream in proxy_pass and set proxy_set_header Host parameter with desired value.